# Python graphical user interface test

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, gui

In my programming class I am learning how to make graphical user interfaces, and so I decided to make one.

```py
import tkinter as t
from random import choice


COLORS = ["white", "black", "red", "green", "blue", "cyan", "yellow", "magenta"]


def button_clicked():
    display_area.config(text = "You clicked the button!")
    screen.itemconfig(epilepsy_man, fill = choice(COLORS))

def epilepsy_man_movment(event):
    key = event.keysym
    if key == "Right":
        screen.move(epilepsy_man, 10, 0)
        screen.itemconfig(epilepsy_man, fill = choice(COLORS))
    elif key == "Left":
        screen.move(epilepsy_man, -10, 0)
        screen.itemconfig(epilepsy_man, fill = choice(COLORS))
    elif key == "Up":
        screen.move(epilepsy_man, 0, -10)
        screen.itemconfig(epilepsy_man, fill = choice(COLORS))
    elif key == "Down":
        screen.move(epilepsy_man, 0, 10)
        screen.itemconfig(epilepsy_man, fill = choice(COLORS))


window = t.Tk()
window.title("Your reading this right now. Please stop.")

button = t.Button(window, text = "Can you click me?", command = button_clicked)
button.pack()

display_area = t.Label(window, text = "Go on! Click the button!")
display_area.pack()

screen = t.Canvas(window, width = 500, height = 500)
screen.pack()
epilepsy_man = screen.create_oval(200, 200, 300, 300, fill = choice(COLORS))
screen.bind_all("<Key>", epilepsy_man_movment)

window.mainloop()
```

**Please note** "epilepsy". If you run this there will be flashing images.

I want to know if I properly followed any conventions, as well as if there is any better way of doing what I have done.

What this program does is make a button that changes the color of the circle and the text on a textbox, as well as creating said textbox and said circle which moves with the arrow keys and changes with each key press.

Comment: Can I have a better explanation of the close vote and the downvotes?

Comment: Most likely due to lack of details about this program. What is its purpose? What specific improvements are you looking for? The more detail about your program, the better.

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled "movement" as "movment".

Typically (as per [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), indentations are specified by one hard tab or four spaces, so you're good in that respect.

To be sure about formatting you can read up on PEP-8.

I am also wondering about `_man`. This doesn't seem to be displaying a man (but I haven't run it) so why name it that way? Also, `epilepsy` doesn't seem like a suitable name. Perhaps `colored_box` would be more formal?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I downvoted because I felt that it did not add anything as it seemed to me the only feedback you gave for me is that I misspelled a word.

Comment: @K00lman Thanks for the feedback. I wouldn't have pointed it out if I didn't feel it was important. Typos might make you look bad to the professor.

Comment: Thanks for that, but this is just something I made in my free time to make sure I get what is being taught. It is not going to be used in my class at all. As such, it's not the most formal.